# Create an image containing .net core sdk and install custom templates inside the image

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, dotnet-new

I am creating a docker image using visual studio console application and the dockerfile looke like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS base
RUN dotnet new --install MyCustomTemplate::1.0.0
WORKDIR /app
    
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerTemplates/DockerTemplates.csproj", "DockerTemplates/"]
RUN dotnet restore "DockerTemplates/DockerTemplates.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerTemplates"
RUN dotnet build "DockerTemplates.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerTemplates.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerTemplates.dll"]
```

After creating the image from sdk, I have called the command to install the custom template using the command:

```
RUN dotnet new --install MyCustomTemplate::1.0.0
```

But when the image is created, I don't find my custom template in my docker image.

**How can I install custom templates inside a image during creation of the image? Anybody can help?**

Thanks

Comment: can you give some more info where you put the "RUN" command? Did you create a new Dockerfile or do you modifiy the existing one? Your command is executed in the defined WORKDIR. Did you choose the correct WORKDIR or do a `cd /my_install_dir && dotnet new ...`?

Comment: Crating a new dockerfile from mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 and the dotnet templates get installed from nuget source

Comment: How do you see that the template isn't there? When I try to replicate your issue, the templates are installed in the image. I don't see the purpose for installing them, but they're there.

Comment: I can also see the standard templats but the new custom template is not installed.

Comment: How do you see that it's not installed?

Comment: In docker desktop, i can give command to check if its installed.
dotnet new --list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to replicate but can't.

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0
RUN dotnet new --install Amazon.Lambda.Templates::5.5.0
```

Commands

```
docker build -t test .
docker run --rm test dotnet new --list
```

Lists the standard templates + the new ones